# Is earning from youtube is halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I have a gaming youtube channel where i post gameplay of different games. Is it halal or haram to do like this??

Answer (score 1):

Aslamu Walaykum

If your videos does not include any bad language, haram relationships, neither does it distract you from the remembering allah, or doing your chores then it is halal to make videos and earn a halal income.